# CoffeeScript extend operator modifying 'this'?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, this, prototype, extend

I recently stumbled over something. I wanted to add the ability to remove an object from an array like this:

```
someArray.remove(element)
```

I wanted to use the `extend` operator of CoffeeScript and do it the following:

```
Array::remove = (element) ->
  return false unless _.include(this, element)
  this = this.splice(_.indexOf(this, element), 1)
  true
```

But the prototype function, that is created points `this` to the `Array` object itself, so the only way is to return something, which would look like this:

```
someArray = someArray.remove(element)
```

and the implementation for that like this:

```
Array::remove = (element) ->
  return this unless _.include(this, element)
  this.splice(_.indexOf(this, element), 1)
```

In ruby this is the exact difference between `join` and `join!`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaken about `splice`. It operates on the array itself. This seems to do the trick, unless I completely misunderstood your question:

```
_ = require "underscore"

Array::remove = (element) ->
  index = _.indexOf @, element
  return false if index is -1
  @splice index, 1
  true

foo = ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log foo            # => ['a', 'b', 'c']
console.log foo.remove "b" # => true
console.log foo            # => ['a', 'c']
console.log foo.remove "d" # => false
console.log foo            # => ['a', 'c']
```

Note that coffeescript includes a shim for `indexOf`, so underscore is not strictly needed, so you could do:

```
Array::remove = (element) ->
  index = @indexOf element
  return false if index is -1
  @splice index, 1
  true
```

Comment: Thanks you, you're right! I didn't know that `splice` is actually modifying the array, I thought it was just returning a new copy.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it as:

```
Array::remove = (element) ->
  return false unless element in @
  @splice(@indexOf(element), 1)
  true
```

And that works fine.  I'm not sure what issue you were having with the `this` variable, but you should note that `splice` changes the original array, so there's no need for the assignment.  Your first implementation doesn't even compile for me, because CoffeeScript doesn't let you assign to `this`.

Comment: Thank you as well, a very elegant solution! Great!